# Using a For Loop to change an If statement

Tags: python

Just a real quick one. I has a list of variables which only change by 1 digit. I want my `if` statement to refer to each individual variable, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Can you help me out?

```
CheckGabba1 = IntVar()
CheckGabba2 = IntVar()
CheckGabba3 = IntVar()
## etc. (x10)

## There are items in these lists (This is just to show that they are lists)
AllEventsGabba = []
SelectedEventsGabba = []

NumEvents = 10
ListIndex = 0

for EventCheck in range(NumEvents):
   if (CheckGabba(ListIndex + 1)).get() == 1:
      SelectedEventsGabba.append(AllEventsGabba[ListIndex])
      ListIndex += 1
   else:
      ListIndex += 1
```

Obviously `(CheckGabba(ListIndex + 1)` is wrong, but I'm not sure what it needs to be replaced with to get the loop to autonomously check each variable, rather than hard-writing (Which I can do, but would prefer not to).

Comment: The usual approach would be having a `CheckGabba` list, so that you can do `CheckGabba[ListIndex + 1]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could group all CheckGabbas in a List and loop over them, like

```
check_list=[CheckGabba1,CheckGabba2,CheckGabba3]
for check in check_list:
    if check.get()==1:
```

an alternative would be to use exec on the string, like

```
exec "CheckGabba("+str(Listindex+1)+")"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understood your question, but to me it looks something like this:

```
# Create a dict of the variables that you want to check later
CheckGabba = {i: IntVar() for i in range(10)}

# Then use a list comprehension to filter the data
SelectedEventsGabba = [event for event in CheckGabba.items() if event == 1]
```